# Story identification: Singer somehow ends up in a fantasy realm with elves (and stuff)

Tags: urban-fantasy, story-identification

The book is about a guy (I'm fairly certain he is a no-success singer) who goes into a cabin in the woods and somehow ends up in another world.

At one point he sings with some elves or dwarfs or something, singing without words which feels right for him.

I also remember there being a love affair where the woman involved has bought some (*ahem*) "**magical enhancers**" but he says they won't need them. It's odd what you remember!

I think there are some weird kind of taxis too.

Comment: When and where did you get the book? Was it part of a series? Do you remember what the cover looked like? Any additional details might help. It sounds reminiscent of *Spellsinger* by Allan Dean Foster (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellsinger_%28novel%29)

Comment: It was not that book. The music didn't really have a big role in it. Unfortunately I do not remember the cover :(
I do appreciate your input though and yes, I believe it was part of a serie or a triology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that's [Tad Williamson's "War of the Flowers"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Flowers). The main character is a talented but unsuccessful singer who is drawn into an alternate word inhabited by elves, goblins, faeries, etc. He does cross over at a cabin, there's a scene where he jams with goblin musicians, and the taxis are driven by donkey-faced, eyeless fae. There's also a scene that mentions sex between a Tinkerbell sized fairy and a human sized one would require "surgery".

[image]

Comment: Ewww ;-) Reminds me of this (Hilarious, but NSFW) http://youtu.be/elAuy2Pgdfw?t=28s

Comment: Thank you Lew. This is the book. Much appreciated.
I did not think anyone would figure it out that quickly with my lacking description.